# Do I need to dissolve left over vertices after combining faces?

Tags: modeling

When I combine faces in edit mode by pressing F, the vertices from the original faces remain. I then manually select all these vertices and dissolve them. As you can see in the example below the image shows 3 selected vertices that I can dissolve. The question is: Is this something that is required in order to optimize a model for a game engine such as Unity? The more complex the model the more of these vertices I find myself cleaning up. Is there an automated way to do this perhaps? [image]

Comment: The answer is yes and no. Depending on how important the model is will be how you should approach the problem. Now the faster way usually leave the model with crippling normals and surface issues and make the model none reworkable. But who cares about a rubbish can on a road side... we don't need details. So it's a good idea to keep a high res model for those unimportant models that uses dirty tools like decimate operation in blender. For characters where details are important say in a game environment. Your best tool is to still do it manually.

Comment: Why do you need to dissolve only middle faces? This creates quite a bit of ngons which may or may not cause troubles, and at the same time amount of faces is still high on the sides of the model. It's better to dissolve across all the model then and maybe go with tris.

Comment: Probably, you needed to select each side and press 'F'. Instead, you should select the two face loops and use 'X' then limited dissolve. Result: the same but without these surplus vertices indicated in the image.

Comment: Also as a side note these days they have LOD tools in game engines to help manage high res models. Sometimes LOD tools works well and sometimes it sucks. Try what works best for your case and projects before committing to lots of workload. Cheers.